# ¿Cómo puedo ajustar una imagen al "Label"?

Tags: python, tkinter, pillow

Cuando muestro una imagen al correr el programa, si la imagen es demasiado grande aparece recortada y ocupando todo o casi todo el espacio. Pido asesoría por favor.

Código:

```
my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('img/pyicon.jpg'))
lab_im = Label(image=my_image)
lab_im.pack()
```

Esta imagen por ejemplo sale así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  supongo que uno de los métodos sería:
img = Image.open("img/pyicon.jpg")
img = img.resize((100,100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
my_image =  ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

lab_im = Label(image=my_image)
lab_im.pack()
```

Saludos

Comment: Funciona, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Para qué sirve "ANTIALIAS"?